# Solution of $x'(t) = - a (x(t)^2 - b^2)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to reproduce the results of a paper and this differential equation

$$x'(t) = - a(x(t)^2 - b^2)$$

is at the heart of the paper where a and b are positive numbers greater than zero.

I cannot see how they arrive at a solution of $x(t) = -b \coth(b(a t+ C_1))$ just by integration.

I have tried solving this differential equation using Mathematica and it gives me a solution of

$$x(t) = b \tanh[b (a t + C[1])]$$

which I don't think is the same. I would like to know how they arrive at this result. Many thanks.

Comment: Mathematical formulas look better in $\LaTeX$. Here (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a quick tutorial.

Comment: @AhmedHussein Here's the english (non-mobile) link :-P https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation

Answer (score 1):

This is a Riccati equation as was said by @YoTengoUnLCD in the comments.

The more general Riccati equation is:

$$x'=Ax^2+Bt^n$$

It is solved by first using the substitution:

$$x(t)=-\frac{1}{A} \frac{y(t)'}{y(t)}$$

Directly substituting, we obtain:

$$-\frac{1}{A} \frac{y''}{y}+\frac{1}{A} \frac{y'^2}{y^2}=\frac{1}{A} \frac{y'^2}{y^2}+Bt^n$$

$$y''+ABt^ny=0$$

In our case $AB=-(ab)^2$ and $n=0$, thus we obtain:

$$y''-(ab)^2y=0$$

But this is just the (imaginary) harmonic oscillator equation. The general solution is:

$$y=C_1 e^{abt}+C_2 e^{-abt}$$

Now getting back to $x(t)$:

> $$x=b \frac{C_1e^{abt}-C_2 e^{-abt}}{C_1 e^{abt}+C_2 e^{-abt}}=b \frac{e^{2ab(t+t_0)}-1}{e^{2ab(t+t_0)}+1}=b \tanh(ab(t+t_0))$$

Here we have:

$$\frac{C_1}{C_2}=e^{2abt_0}$$

This is just the same solution as the one given by Mathematica. If you want to obtain another form of solution, used in the paper, you need to set:

$$\frac{C_1}{C_2}=-e^{2abt_0}$$

Then you will have:

> $$x=b \frac{-e^{2ab(t+t_0)}-1}{-e^{2ab(t+t_0)}+1}=-b \coth(ab(t+t_0))$$